# How to get Windows version by name (for future Windows versions)?

Tags: c, winapi

I can use the `GetVersionEx()` function to get the Windows version, but this function will return a number and not a string. But there is no problem as I can convert the number to a string, for example:

```
if (osvi.dwMajorVersion == 6 && osvi.dwMinorVersion == 1)
{
    printf("%s\n", "Windows 7");
}
```

But what if a new Windows version came out after releasing my program. I have to recompile my program to add the new Windows version!

Answer (score 3):

You should query `Caption` of [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

You could query the system registry and get the data from the following location. To see the registry functions visit the MSDN page of [Registry Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`

**Information Provided**

- ProductName: The Operation System Name ex "Windows 8.1"
- SoftwareType: The type of the software ex "System" or "Server"
- CurrentVersion: It contains the version such as 6.3

Comment: Who says that key will still be used in a future release. Is it documented now?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are completely correct. I couldn't find any reference that this key will exist in the future. The best solution is to use [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and com calls from C. I just wanted to provide another option.